# maven-dependency-plugin unpack goal: do not overwrite existing files

Tags: maven

I do not ever want `maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:unpack` to overwrite existing files in any circumstances. This is my current `pom.xml` configuration:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-zip-files</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
              <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
              <version>${foobar.version}</version>
              <type>zip</type>
              <classifier>exe-archive</classifier>
              <overWrite>false</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <includes>**/*.exe</includes>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <overWriteIfNewer>false</overWriteIfNewer>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Scenario:

- Projects `foo` and `bar`
- `foo` has a `.exe` file as build artifact, inside a ZIP file
- `bar` runs the `.exe` file during tests
- In situation X, `bar` must use the snapshot version of the mainline development branch of `foo`. In that case, the directory `target/lib` shall be empty before `mvn install`. This is guaranteed by starting from an empty workspace and running `mvn clean` as a separate build step. This question is not about situation X.
- In situation Y, `bar` must use a custom build of a feature branch of `foo`. This is done by unpacking the ZIP file with the `.exe` to the directory `target/lib` in a separate build step *between* `mvn clean` and `mvn install`.

We are working in situation Y, where the `target/lib` directory is already pre-filled with the `.exe` from the correct feature branch.

This is the `target/lib` directory *before* `mvn` is run:

```
+ ls -al fooBar.exe
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 18368427 Apr 12 21:27 fooBar.exe
+ md5sum fooBar.exe
03acc8b5c3da700c31efcd6635feb56a  fooBar.exe
```

This is the `target/lib` directory *after* `mvn` is run:

```
+ ls -al fooBar.exe
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 18368393 Apr 11 23:10 fooBar.exe
+ md5sum fooBar.exe
ab6dd45c5cc4e41534ad2363c5767601  fooBar.exe
```

The change in `md5sum` is hard evidence that the existing `fooBar.exe` was overwritten by Maven.

Maven command used:

```
mvn --global-settings /home/jenkins/workspace/bar@tmp/config15592668079584895681tmp \
    -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/workspace/bar/.repository \
    install \
    -DgsExec=/usr/bin/gs -DcompareExec=/usr/local/bin/compare \
    -Dtest=RunCucumberTest -Dcucumber.options=--plugin json:target/cucumber.json
```

**Expected results**

- The `mvn install` command shall not overwrite existing files when `overWrite`, `overWriteIfNewer`, `overWriteReleases`, `overWriteSnapshots` are all set to **`false`**.
- The `md5sum` of `fooBar.exe` shall be the same before and after running `mvn install`.

**Question**

Which magical incantations do I need to add to `pom.xml` so that existing files are never overwritten in any circumstances?

**Documentation referenced**

- [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin – Usage – Overwrite Rules](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#Overwrite_Rules)
- [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin – dependency:unpack](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html)

Comment: Can you show the command you are using? Furthermore why using dependency:unpack...

Comment: @khmarbaise *"the command you are using"* -> do you mean the `mvn` command? Please confirm or clarify. Meanwhile I have added the full `mvn` command.

Comment: @khmarbaise *"why using dependency:unpack"* -> please clarify your question.

Comment: Asked on users@maven.apache.org mailing list: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r7e849071ffcc0fad79c7708dcca5a536862d2c6423f809b7750ad676%40%3Cusers.maven.apache.org%3E. If I get an answer there, then I'll also post it here.

Comment: Actually, I just read your message on the mailing list and tried in one of my own projects, also using plugin version 3.1.2. Actually, just specifying `<overWrite>false</overWrite>` inside the `<artifactItem>` was enough to avoid overwriting. I just executed the unpack goal once, then manually modified an unpacked file and it did not get overwritten. I even see `my-artifact-1.3.jar already unpacked` in the log. So I am requesting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem, ideally on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I know what might be happening: Like I said in my comment:

> I just read your message on the mailing list and tried in one of my own projects, also using plugin version 3.1.2. Actually, just specifying `<overWrite>false</overWrite>` inside the `<artifactItem>` was enough to avoid overwriting. I just executed the unpack goal once, then manually modified an unpacked file and it did not get overwritten. I even see `my-artifact-1.3.jar already unpacked` in the log.

I continued experimenting some more and noticed that even when deleting many unpacked files, they will not be recreated, so the check must be on a more global level, not on a per-file basis.

Even when deleting all files or the whole output directory, the dependency will not be unpacked again. That was a sure indicator that some kind of meta information must be stored somewhere outside the output directory. The first place to look for it was of course the `target` directory, and obviously enough, in subdirectory `target/dependency-maven-plugin-markers` there are (empty) marker files like `my-dependency-1.3.marker`. Deleting one of those files has the effect of the dependency getting unpacked again during the next build, overwriting possibly existing files.

So the way for you to solve this problem is to avoid cleaning the `target` directory or at least to make sure to keep the corresponding marker file.

---

**Update:** You could also create the marker file by yourself if the EXE file you want to protect exists and if for some reason your build workflow needs the `clean` in between. But the latter would be a bit ugly, you should try to avoid it. With Antrun or some Beanshell or Groovy scripting it would be possible, though.

Somewhat more elegant would be a profile with auto-activation if the EXE file does not exist, then putting the dependency plugin inside the profile, i.e. it would only get active if the EXE does not exist in the first place.

Comment: Please note my updated answer for a workaround if you cannot avoid `mvn clean` for some reason.

Comment: A profile with `<activation><file><missing>${project.build.directory}/lib/fooBar.exe</missing></file></activation>`? That indeed looks like the most elegant solution I can find so far. https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-model/maven.html#class_file

Comment: I tried creating the marker file with Groovy scripting but that lead nowhere.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, similar to what I did in a few cases [here](https://github.com/kriegaex/org.aspectj/blob/5c34265be69ec2e0380c4b9dcc2553b08ddd6bd8/libx/pom.xml#L292-L299) (you will find 4 instances in that file). I just mentioned creating the marker file via script, but actually scripted builds are ugly, they feel like Ant, not Maven. The activation on missing file definitely is the better alternative. I am curious, though: Why can you not just avoid to clean the module?

Comment: I would really love to answer that question, but I can't. Not on a public website where I am not anonymous. :-) Can I send you a message on one of your coordinates mentioned in your profile?

Comment: Feel free to contact me.

Comment: I can now confirm that it works with profiles with auto-activation based on missing files. If the file exists, then the profile is skipped. Pull request to the repo will be merged soon.